# How to change the size of bootstrap sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to change the size of bootstrap sidebar.
I want it to be a bit smaller so I could have more space in the main.

[Bootstrap example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/)

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 sidebar">
```

Changing this line to

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-1 sidebar">
```

will change the size of column to 1 column for mid screen size

you should really read the full documentations before starting

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

The other way to do it is using the customize optionin bootstrap

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Go to the number of columns field
Find

**Grid system**
Define your custom responsive grid.

increase your values there